# Can Lightning Communities have sub-pages?

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-community, community-cloud

So the current iteration of my website contains several sub-pages on the home page. Navigating from Home, they can go to `www.website.com/Home` to `www.website.com/Home/Directory` or `www.website.com/Home/version2`. In trying to switch to communities, I have yet to find a way to provide that same level of the hierarchy. It seems like Communities only allow users to go one level deep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Until Winter 21 Release**, you **could not** add the URL level(s) (depth) of custom standard pages. When you try to do that you will get the next error

> Include only alphanumeric characters and hyphens

.
[image]

So you can either

- [Create different Community Custom Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_create_page.htm&type=5) with different URLs
- Create different [Page Variations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_create_page.htm&type=5) and assign them to different [Audiences](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5) if you want to create alternative versions of the same page.
- Or you can even [assign audiences to Community Page Components](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_audience_component.htm&type=5) making it that much easier to get the right content in front of the right members.

It all depends on the appropriateness of using one or another approach in the context of the set requirements.

**UPDATE: Winter 21 Release**
[Own page hierarchy](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_networks_page_actions.htm) for Lightning Communities is available now.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your suggestions are appreciated, and I'll see if any of those are viable in the context of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to add subpages in Lightning Communities. The feature appeared (silently?) sometime after the Summer '20 release - unexpected (did not notice in the release notes) but very welcome.

[image: Add Subpage menu item - yes, sub-sub-pages are possible too]

[image: Create subpage name and URL dialog]